# fetch() function not defined on ubuntu chromium browser

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, firefox, chromium

I wrote a script with js and php that uses the fetch(url) function. In windows10 it works with both firefox 46 and chrome 50 works fine. When I moved to ubuntu though, it gives me an "fetch is not defined" error on chromium and on firefox it gives me a json parse error when I fetch the url and then try to response.json() it. 
Does chromium support fetch()? And is it possible that the same function on the same version of firerox (46.0.1) works differently on windows 10 and ubuntu?

** EDIT ADDED CODE **

```
function getStudioData() {
  var url='../sitSt.json';
  fetch(url).then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  }).then(function(data) {
    putStData(data);              // function that displays the fetched datas
  }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log ('ERRORE ', err);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

the `fetch()` method is still experimentally and not working in each of the "great" browsers (such as FF). You can see the browser compatibility in the link i posted above.

greetings

Comment: I saw that, page. The browsers versions I'm using should support the fetch() function, besides FF is not giving me problems with that, chromium is. Does chromium have the same specifics as Chrome or are they different? FF(ubuntu) has problems only with response.json() not on windows10 and I wanted to know it the OS can influence the script of if there is something else I need to look at

Comment: all of them use the Mozilla Engine - please update your question with your code

Comment: I've updated, this is the function that fives me Uncaucht ReferenceError: fetch is not defined on chromium on ubuntu, while it works on chrome+FF on windows 10. I also tried to change the url and fetch http://www.google.com, just to test it. it gives me the same error

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch) then.